nvidia-smi got `No devices were found` on second run but it's ok in first run after reboot
I tried to install Nvidia driver on a VPS with PCIe Passthrough

System info:

Ubuntu 22 Server
VmWare VPS (14 core CPU) (24GB of RAM)
Nvidia driver 520
GPU RTX 3060

The Problem:
After OS reboot nvidia-smi shows GPU correctly but when I try again it returns No devices were found.
Installation Steps:
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf >>

blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo reboot

Remove Intel Microcode
sudo dpkg -l | grep intel
sudo apt purge intel-microcode
sudo update-grub

Then add
UFEI secure boot OFF
hypervisor.cpuid.v0=FALSE to VM Configuration Parameters

Install development tools for build Nvidia driver
sudo apt update && sudo apt install gcc make  build-essential libglvnd-dev pkg-config

Install Nvidia Driver from .run file:
sudo init 3
chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-520.56.06.run
./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-520.56.06.run  -m=kernel-open

Install without kernel signing Then:
/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia.conf >>

options nvidia NVreg_OpenRmEnableUnsupportedGpus=1

Then reboot.
How can I troubleshoot system errors? Is there any missing thing?
